# Crashes with multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer, crash, sdl-2

I am currently making a game using SDL2, and I started using timers, and I have a callback set to a function that calls SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface.  I then saw online that SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface should only be called from the main thread, so I set up a queue system in which the timer thread can add it's request to the queue for calling SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface, and the main thread goes through the queue and actually calls it.  My problem is now happening when I tried to create a mutex for the queue-adding function on the timer thread, and the main thread, going through the queue and processing an entry.

I made a wrapper for SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface to add entries into the queue.

multithread_protection.cpp (function called from timer thread):

```
#include "multithread_protection.h"
#include <SDL.h>


#include <mutex>

std::mutex mutex;

bool bQueueCurrentlyProcessing = false;
std::vector<function_t> queue;

SDL_Texture * SDLCALL Queue_SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(SDL_Renderer * renderer, SDL_Surface * surface)
{
mutex.lock();

function_t func;
func.renderer = renderer;
func.surface = surface;
func.pOutput = 0;

if (queue.size() == 0)
{
    func.id = 0;
}
else if (queue.size() > 0)
{
    func.id = queue[queue.size() - 1].id + 1;
}

queue.push_back(func);

mutex.unlock();

while (true)
{
    mutex.lock();

    for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++)
    {
        if (queue[i].id == func.id)
        {
            // This entry is validated as the one that we put in.

            if (queue[i].pOutput)
            {
                SDL_Texture *pOutputCopy = queue[i].pOutput;
                ////bQueueCurrentlyProcessing = true;
                ////queue[i].acknowledged_completed = true;
                //if (!pOutputCopy)
                //{
                //  int a;
                //  a = 5;
                //}

                return pOutputCopy;
                return 0;
            }

            i = 0;
        }
    }
    mutex.unlock();
}


}
```

multithread_protection.h:

```
struct function_t
{
SDL_Renderer * renderer;
SDL_Surface * surface;
unsigned int id;

SDL_Texture *pOutput;
bool acknowledged_completed = false;
};

extern bool bQueueCurrentlyProcessing;
extern std::vector<function_t> queue;

extern std::mutex mutex;

SDL_Texture * SDLCALL Queue_SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(SDL_Renderer * renderer, SDL_Surface * surface);
```

render.cpp (main thread):

```
void HandleMultithreadedFunctionQueue()
{
mutex.lock();

//bQueueCurrentlyProcessing = true;
for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++)
{
    if (queue[i].pOutput == 0) // This entry hasn't been processed yet.
    {
        queue[i].pOutput = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(queue[i].renderer, queue[i].surface);
    }
    if (queue[i].acknowledged_completed)
    {
        //queue.erase(queue.begin() + i); // Erase entry from queue since it finished, and we don't need it anymore.
    }
}
//bQueueCurrentlyProcessing = false;

mutex.unlock();
}
```

The mutexes keep crashing the program and sometimes causes weird blocking.  If someone can please tell me how to better handle this multithreaded situation, that would be great.  Thanks!

Edit:
I tried using std::lock_guard, std::unique_lock, and std::condition_variable, but sadly have no luck.  Maybe I'm using them incorrectly in my situation?  Can somebody give me some examples of how to use them in my situation please?  Thanks.

Comment: Use `std::lock_guard` for RAII-style locking and unlocking.

Comment: Avoid manual locking and unlocking like the plague. You probably need a combination of `std::unique_lock` and `std::condition_variable`.

Answer (score 1):

Use of global variables and manual mutex locking / unlocking is a solid ground for all kinds of threading issues. For example at `return pOutputCopy;` locked mutex is not unlocked which leads to hangs and to undefined behavior when it is locked again by the same thread. At least use `::std::lock_guard` to deal with mutex locks.